# spresenseのメインボードのピンアサインで 6-9, 12,13 ピンを GPIO として利用可能か？

Tags: spresense, gpio

SPRESENSEの仕様書を見ると、以下の3つに分かれています。

- CXD5602ピンネーム
- Ardirnoピンネーム
- Functoinピンネーム

外部接続に2つのUARTとGPIOが6つ必要で、UARTの1つはメインボードCN2のマイクロUSBを使用し、残りの1つとGPIOから接続したいと考えています。この場合、2,3ピンでUART通信をし、6-9ピンと12、13をGPIOとして利用したいと考えています。

CXD5602ピンネームでは6-9と12、13ピンはI2S、SPI、IRQと書かれていますが、これを単なるGPIOとして利用することは可能でしょうか?

Answer (score 1):

質問内容を読み解いて2-13ピンが下の図のピンであるということを前提とすると、2,3ピン（D01,D00）をUARTとして利用しつつ、6-9,12ピンはGPIO(D26,D25,D24,D23,D22)として利用することが可能です。しかし、13ピンはアナログ入力(A2)なので、GPIOとして利用することはできません。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: ご丁寧な回答ありがとうございました。
13ピンはアナログでしたね。失礼しました。
UARTはフロー制御を行わないため、4,5ピンもGPIOに割り当てたいと思います。

Comment: 1,2 をUARTにすると4,5 もUARTとして機能してしまうので使用できないと思います。D16, D17 (18,19ピン？)あたりを使うとよいと思います。どうしても右側にピンを寄せたい場合（4,5 を使いたい）で Baudrate を必要としないなら、1,2 を SoftwareSerial として使うという手もあります。（その場合はUARTが1,2ピンである必要もありませんが…）https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/arduino_developer_guide_ja.html#_software_serial_%E3%83%A9%E3%82%A4%E3%83%96%E3%83%A9%E3%83%AA

Comment: UART設定の場合は、3,4ピンはGPIOでは使えないということですね。ありがとうございました。JP2側を使えば解決可能なので、そちらで検討いたします。